# Write a Sub to repeat while a button control is held down

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a form in my application that opens to allow a user to enter a time by either clicking on an up or down button for each digit (hour, minute, second) or directly entering the digits with a keyboard.  Here is a capture of the form:

[image]

I am trying to code an event handler attached to the `MouseDown` event that will delay for two seconds, then begin incrementing the digit up or down (depending on the button held down) until the the button is released.

If I haven't provided enough information, please let me know and I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is already built in to the DateTimePicker just change a few properties and the user clicks on the time portion to scroll through before using the updown buttons:

```
    Me.DateTimePicker1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.DateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Time
    Me.DateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = True
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using WPF, you can use a [`RepeatButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.repeatbutton.aspx) instead of a `Button`

sample from MSDN:

```
<RepeatButton Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
              Delay="500" Interval="100" 
              Click="Increase">
  Increase
</RepeatButton>

Private Sub Increase(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)    
    Num = CInt(valueText.Text)    
    valueText.Text = ((Num + 1).ToString())
End Sub
```

For WinForms, [this tutorial from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5289/A-Simple-Auto-Repeat-Button-on-VB-NET) has everything you need to know.

Comment: +1 for covering both WinForms and WPF (since OP didn't specify which). :)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial! I will look it over and play with it for a bit.  One other thing... I want the buttons to increment by one if clicked and released but repeat if held down for > 2 seconds.  Again, I will let you all know how I make out!  Thanks again!